# Python reassembly PCAP JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, networking

I am working on a Python script that will read a `pcapng` file and then return the JSON data in the HTTPResponse layer back to me. I have some code working but I ran into an issue where the packet doesn't contain all of the data.

```
from scapy.all import IP, sniff
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers import http
from scapy.utils import *
import json

def process_tcp_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(Raw):
        l = packet.getlayer(Raw)
        k = l.load  

        try:
            p = json.loads(k)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        print(p)

sniff(offline='cap.pcapng', prn=process_tcp_packet, count=7)
```

This is what I have so far and it will print out the JSON data but since it doesn't get it all it fails in the `try` block because it doesn't have a ending `'`. I need a way to put the packets back together so when I parse the JSON it has all the data

Comment: A single TCP packet doesn't necessarily hold the entire JSON file. It may be fragmented across different TCP packets. Maybe this can help: https://github.com/deeso/scapy-tcp-extractor

Comment: So is TCP Reassembly all I need to put the JSON back together?

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, yes